# Django two apps frontend and backend

Tags: python, django, yii2

I am new in Django so I have a question for start working with it. Now I am writing my apps in PHP and Yii2. In Yii, I have to separate apps (frontend and backend) with two auth mechanism. But I want go to Python with Django I know that is admin site but I dont know how to clone functionality like Yii2. I need two different pages for login users (admin and normal users) and 2 panels for them.

Should I use two difference instances of admin site or write it manually?

Comment: Can you please give more details and make a more precise questions, so we can understand the problem.

Comment: I need to write application where users can login to their part of applications and admins login to their own part. So I dont know, just use two Admin sites modules (one for users and one for admins, I dont want users login in the same page with admins) and use admin module for "admin" and write own panel for users.

Comment: @user246439 just keep the admin for the admins and build the rest with the classic Model-View-Template model of django, nobody is gonna code for you,we can only give you guidance :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have two different instances. Since the admin pages (backend) are shipped with django out of the box, you can just start building the frontend. Be sure to register your sites to the admin pages for the models you are using.
I recommend going through the great django documentation:
[Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/)

The django-admin is pretty straightforward and works great out of the box. You are somehow limited in terms of customization though. It depends on what your goals are an how much functionality your administration needs.

More infos [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/).